# Scala resources for beginners

Tags: scala

Please suggest where to find useful and interesting Scala

- articles
- code examples
- sites to communicate with Scala experts

What kind of project (multithreading, web based project) should be good to start code in Scala in order to show all power of the language?
So, please suggest a task for first Scala project.

Comment: best scala resources books, videos, tutorials http://tomer-ben-david.github.io/best-scala-resources-tutorials-books-videos.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started learning Scala an year back and the below I think is the besy way forward:

1. Functional Programming in Scala by Martin odersky - course on coursera is Excellent. It will get you quickly started with the tools and introduction (repl mode, worksheet, compile and run etc). Also gives you a very good understanding of functional paradigms and covers the syntactic sugar well. I think the best place to start.
2. Then look at [Twitter Scala School](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/).
3. Get to know scala Future API well.
4. Look at TypeSafe stack. Get started with Akka (I learnt the most about Scala looking at their source, the way they used PartialFunctions for `receive`, DSL's etc). It will show you vastness and beauty of Scala as a language.
5. Last but not the least, learning from questions & answers here at StackOVerFlow. Not more than 25 questions are asked in a day. If you are from Java world, then you will feel Scala is vast. SO will get your attention towards many topics.
6. If time permits, look at [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)

Comment: Best scalaz introduction that I know: [learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/).

Comment: If you are doing a google search for the first rec, it's 'Functional Programming Principles in Scala'.

Answer (score 2):

Scala for the Impatient By Cay Horstmann.

The first half of the book is available for free online (via [Typesafe](http://typesafe.com/resources/book/scala-for-the-impatient) for example) and it is a great and easy way to start.

The [Twitter Scala School](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/) mentioned by @Jatin is also a great resource.

[Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) and [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html) are one of the most powerful tools in Scala and can be used for vast purposes so you can start from there but it is hard (to impossible) to see all the power of the language in a first project.